# Fixed points of a system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I'm wondering about how to find the fixed points for the following system:

$$
\dot{x} = \frac{xr_1}{k_1}\left(k_1 - c_1 x - i_1 y \right)
$$

$$
\dot{y} = \frac{y r_2}{k_2}\left(k_2 - c_2 y - i_2 x \right)
$$

I think the approach would be;

For $\dot{x}$ I can state that either $x=0$ or the term in the parenthesis is
zero. For the term the parenthesis, consider $x=0$ and $y=0$ separately. This
gives the points $(0, k_1/i_1)$ when $x=0$ and $(k_1/c_1 , 0)$ when $y=0$.

The same approach is taken for $\dot{y}$ which gives $(0, k_2/c_2)$ when $x=0$
and $(k_2/i_2, 0)$ when $y=0$.

This gives the fixed points

- $(0 , 0)               $
- $(0 , \frac{k_1}{i_1}) $, (from $\dot{x}$, where $x=0$)
- $(\frac{k_1}{c_1} , 0) $, (from $\dot{x}$, where $y=0$)
- $(0 , \frac{k_2}{c_2}) $, (from $\dot{y}$, where $x=0$)
- $(\frac{k_2}{c_2} , 0) $, (from $\dot{y}$, where $y=0$)

Comment: Hint: a fixed point is such that $\dot x=\dot y=0$ and this leaves a system of two equations in two unknowns.

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks - I'm a bit confused about the case where we have $x$ as part
of the fixed point, rather than it being purely coefficients.
Here : 
$$
y = \frac{(k_1 - k_2) + x(i_2 - c_1) }{c_2 - i_1}
$$
or
$$
x = \frac{(k_1 - k_2) + y(c_2 - i_1) }{i_2 - c_1}
$$

Comment: I mean, if I have a fixed point of the form 
$$
\left( \frac{k_1 - k_2}{c_1 - i_2} , \frac{x(c_1 - i_2) - k_1 + k_2}{c_2 - i_1}  \right)
$$
Then when I evaulate it with the Jacobian it's not the same, usually the values are all constants that can be plugged in.

Comment: No, write down the system of equations and solve it. If I am right, there are five distinct solutions.

Comment: Er, I mean four solutions. You may not consider one equation at a time.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not correct.

For example, if $x=0$ then $\dot x=0$ **already**, so you shouldn't look at the other factor in $\dot x$ in that case.

The correct cases are:

- $x = 0$ and $y = 0$

or

- $x = 0$ and $k_2 - c_2 y - i_2 x = 0$

or

- $k_1 - c_1 x - i_1 y = 0$ and $y = 0$

or

- $k_1 - c_1 x - i_1 y = 0$ and $k_2 - c_2 y - i_2 x = 0$

Each of these cases gives you one fixed point $(x,y)$, so there are four fixed points in total (the origin, one on each axis, plus a nontrivial one).

Comment: Thanks, are the indices correct in what you've written?

Comment: Oops, sorry, forgot to change $i_1$ to $i_2$ after copying. Now it should be OK.

Comment: Thanks, for the last case I'm not sure how to write the point down, it seems that I would have
$$
y = \frac{(k_1 - k_2) + x(i_2 - c_1) }{c_2 - i_1}
$$
or
$$
x = \frac{(k_1 - k_2) + y(c_2 - i_1) }{i_2 - c_1}
$$
Is this correct?

Comment: It's a $2 \times 2$ linear system (two equations, two unknowns). Just solve it as you would in linear algebra.

Comment: ok, do you have a link to an answer that covers that I could review?

Comment: Surely linear algebra is a prerequisite for an ODE course where a problem like this would appear?!? Anyway, this is extremely basic stuff, just google “Gaussian elimination” and you will find a million explanations.

Comment: I was interested in seeing one in this context, of which millions wouldn't appear from googling what you've suggested. Sorry this is so shocking for you

Comment: Just solve $$\pmatrix{c_1&i_1\\i_2&c_2}\pmatrix{x\\y}=\pmatrix{k_1\\k_2},$$ for instance using Cramer's rule or by multiplying with the adjoint matrix $$\pmatrix{c_2&-i_1\\-i_2&c_1}$$ from the left.